# A number in placeholder / title

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, field, title

In my little WP project I have got a title field in a form (wp job manager) which I need to be disabled but also I would like to automaticaly insert a number into it so when the form is POSTed the number will be saved as a title name. 
I was thinking do it somehow with placeholder but I cannot find the way.

```js
'job_title' => array(
    'label'       => __( 'Job Title', 'wp-job-manager' ),
    'type'        => 'text',
    'required'    => false,
    'placeholder' => '',
    'priority'    => 1
),
```

or second option if there is any script which can automaticaly assign POST ID or a number to empty titles?

Thank you so much if there is anyone who could help. I worked on this couple hours and cannot find a working solution as I am a php beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either assign number using `onsubmit` attribute of form. You can add javascript function/code in onsubmit attribute.

Or

Assign value to field on page load.